# Using toggle CSS in JQuery (JSFiddle): POST request?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

JSFiddle link below. How can I toggle this menu to open and collapse on click? My JQuery is having a POST request issue and I"m not sure why I would even need that for something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navi1" class="navi">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link1</</li>
        <li><a href="" class="sel">Link2</</li>
        <li><a href="">Link3</</li>
        <li><a href="">Link4</</li>
        <li><a href="">Link5</</li>
        <li><a href="">Link6</</li>
        <li><a href="">Link7</</li>
        <li><a href="">Link8</</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navi1 ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#navi1 li a {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:300px;
    background:pink;
    z-index:998;
}
#navi1 li a.sel {
    z-index:999;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navi1").click(function () {
        $("#navi1 li a").css("position", "relative");
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Sj2bD/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this proper practice but adding `javascript:;` to your anchor's href will prevent the anchor's default action from execution:

```
<li><a href="javascript:;">Link1</a></li>


$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#navi1").click(function () {
       $("#navi1 li a").css("position", "relative");
   });
});
```

Code: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj2bD/2/)

Comment: If you need to complete the expand / collapse behavior, I recommend you revise your current css layout. Manipulating `position` is not the elegant way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Also, if you pass the event (i.e., .click(function (event) { ... ) and add the event.preventDefault() to the script. It should prevent the a from firing as usual.